# Derivation of Moment of Inertia and centre of mass?

Tags: integration, moment-of-inertia

[image]

In the equation above for the MI for a rod, why are we taking the limits from -l/2 to l/2?

And why doesn't the integral doesn't include the centre of mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits run where they are because you're taking the moment about the center of the rod, which means that the center (x=0) of your coordinate system is the middle of the rod.

As for your second question, it doesn't make a ton of sense to me -- the integral runs through the center of mass, but moment of inertia and center of mass are two different concepts.